# How to access scope outside of ng-repeat in a directive

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular directive and a list of items:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in topics">
  <p change-content-on-click>{{ x.name }}</p>
</li>

app.directive('changeContentOnClick', function(TopicService) {
   return{
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function(scope, element) {
           element.bind('click', function(){
               scope.message = "hello";
               scope.$apply();
           });
       }
   }
});
```

What I need to do is bind `{{ message }}` which is outside the repeat to a clicked item in the list. How can I do that? I went through a lot of documentation but I couldn't find.

Comment: Looks pretty good to me. Is the click function invoked? For example, if you do a `console.log` inside the bind function?

Comment: updated to work as expected, see plunker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass it in as an attribute with two way data binding

```
<li ng-repeat="x in topics">
  <p change-content-on-click some-attr="message">{{ x.name }}</p>
</li>

<div ng-bind='message'></div> <!-- same as {{message}} but less messy on failure -->
```

JS:

```
$scope.message = {text:""}; 

app.directive('changeContentOnClick', function() {
   return{
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: { 
           someAttr: "=" 
       },
       link: function(scope, element) {
           element.bind('click', function(){
               scope.message = "hello";
               scope.someAttr.text = scope.message;
               scope.$apply(); // not sure that you need this
               console.log(scope.message);
           });
       } 
   } 
});
```

Updated:
Fixed according to below comments, you're right, forgot you cant just assign to string, need an object.

http://plnkr.co/edit/1qTLzk41jzrWiGLRiZG9?p=preview

Comment: It think, this does not work. pass message as an object property and use dot notation "some-attr=someObj.message" may help.

Comment: Actually Alborz is correct. Can't just pass in a primative (`message` is a string, need to pass in object for 2 way binding to work). Also `scope.$apply()` is needed because it's in a jqLite callback.

Comment: It doesn't quite work for me yet. Maybe it's to do with some else I've got going on here..

Comment: I updated the code above, works as expected. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @greener, this should meet your needs now.